# Evaluating Posfix using Stack (LinkedList)

Tags: java, collections, stack, postfix-notation

*I need to evaluate postfix expressions using a linked list stack. I think i need some help with the algorithm. I write* `13+` *as input but i get `100` as output.*

PostfixCalculator Class:

```
public class PostfixCalculator{
    String expression;
    MyStack stack = new MyStack<Double>();

    public PostfixCalculator(String postFixExpression)
    {
         expression = postFixExpression;
    }

    public String calculate()
    {
        String output = "";
        char character = ' ';
        double digit = 0;

        for(int x = 0; x < expression.length(); x++)
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(x))) {
                    digit = expression.charAt(x);
            }
            character = expression.charAt(x);
            if(expression.charAt(x) == digit)
            {
                stack.push(digit);
            }
            else if(character == '*')
            {
                double tmp = (double) stack.pop() * (double) stack.pop();
                stack.push(tmp);
            }
            else if(character == '/')
            {
                double tmp = (double) stack.pop() / (double) stack.pop();
                stack.push(tmp);
            }
            else if(character == '+')
            {
                double tmp = (double) stack.pop() + (double) stack.pop();
                stack.push(tmp);
            }
            else if(character == '-')
            {
                double tmp = (double) stack.pop() - (double) stack.pop();
                stack.push(tmp);
            }
        }

        while(!stack.isEmpty())
        {
            output = output + (double) stack.pop();
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

PostfixCalculatorTest Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PostfixCalculatorTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type the postfix expression that you want to evaluate");
        String expression = input.next();
        PostfixCalculator calculator = new PostfixCalculator(expression);
        System.out.println(calculator.calculate());
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one thing, you are pushing characters into `MyStack` that is declared to hold `Double`. This will force a conversion from `char` to `double` and print the numerical value of your characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First this

```
if(Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(x))) {
     digit = expression.charAt(x);
}
```

saves the decimal [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) value of the char at the position x as double, for the char `'1'` it is `49`, for `'3'` it is `51`, hence you get `100` as result

it should be

```
digit = Double.parseDouble("" + expression.charAt(x));
```

i.e. parse the char to get the double value it represents.

Here is the small change

```
character = expression.charAt(x);
if(Character.isDigit(character)) {
    digit = Double.parseDouble("" + character);
    stack.push(digit);
}
```

then it would work for `13+` and give `4` as result.

Those line can be removed:

```
character = expression.charAt(x);
if(expression.charAt(x) == digit)
{
    stack.push(digit);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is automatic type conversion. Java is able to convert a `char` into a `double`. What you get is the ASCII-Code of the `char` '1' (49) and the ASCII-Code of the `char` '3' (51). So your program does in theory the right thing, except you have to substract 48 (being the ASCII-Code for `0`) from the actual ASCII-Codes you read in. You should refractor your porgram with this fact in mind.

Besides: is there a reason, why you:

- use a self-written Stack instead of java.util.Stack?
- Make the Stack a Container for Double instead of Integer?

Comment: ohh it is a homework actually and our teacher wanted us to use a self-written on. and i thought there can me some decimal values when it is dividing so i used it. thank you for helping :)

Comment: You should be careful with these kind of changes (regarding `Double`) since the `integer`-division is clearly defined. Your porgram does no longer meet these definement.